# Birational isomorphism $\mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{P}^m\to \mathbb{P}^{n+m}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

One can show that $\mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{P}^m$ is birational to $\mathbb{P}^{n+m}$ by making note of the Zariski topologies and the canonical isomorphism between affine spaces $\mathbb{A}^n\times \mathbb{A}^m\to \mathbb{A}^{n+m}$.

*Question*: Does it follow that there is isomorphism $\mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{P}^m\to \mathbb{P}^{n+m}$? If so, what is an example of such an isomorphism?

Unfortunately I am having a hard time coming up with one, and haven't seen too many examples thus far.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You have already produced a birational isomorphism? What definition of rational map are you using?

Comment: What would make sense is whether there exists a birational *morphism* from $\mathbb P^n\times \mathbb P^m$ to $\mathbb P^{n+m}$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You're absolutely right, I mistyped and should have just wrote "isomorphism," e.g. a regular map with a regular inverse as Robert points out below.

Answer (score 4):

As a user commented above, your question is a bit confusing since you already gave a birational map between $\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^m\to\mathbb{P}^{n+m}$. Now, if you are looking for an isomorphism, that is, a regular map with a regular inverse, this can't exist. One way is to see this is that $\mbox{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^m)\simeq\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mbox{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^{n+m})\simeq\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Is there a more elementary way to see that an isomorphism doesn't exist without sheaf-theoretic language? Nevertheless, your note that $\text{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{P}^m)\ncong \text{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^{n+m})$ is very helpful.

Comment: Yes, I can show this in a more elementary way. Take $H_1,\ldots,H_{n+m}\subseteq\mathbb{P}^n$ general hyperplanes; since $n+m>n$ we get that $H_1\cap\cdots\cap H_{n+m}=\varnothing$. Take $L_i:= H_i\times\mathbb{P}^m$. We have that the $L_i$ are irreducible subvarieties of codimension 1, and $L_1\cap\cdots\cap L_{n+m}=\varnothing$. However, in $\mathbb{P}^{m+n}$, any collection of $n+m$ codimension 1 subvarieties intersect non-trivially.

Comment: One can also work with less subvarieties. Suppose $n\ge m$. Take two distinct points $x_1, x_2$ in $\mathbb P^m$. Then $\mathbb P^n\times \{ x_1\}$ and $\mathbb P^n \times \{ x_2\}$ are two closed subsets without intersection. But the sum of their dimensions $n+n$ is bigger or equal to $n+m$. Such situation can't happen in $\mathbb P^{n+m}$.